# How do I remove an old watch from Apple Health sources?

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

Every Watch I've ever had is listed among sources in Apple Health, and I see no way to remove or even disable them.

How do I delete old Watches (including ones I no longer own and that have been unpaired) from Apple Health's list of data sources?